# Helping out a Newbie with Linear Algebra in TensorFlow (Rank 3 Tensors)

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication

I suspect that this has already been asked, although in my searching, many of the other problems had specific unique issues that don't seem as applicable to my situation (or maybe the solutions were over my head).

I have a standard feed forward neural net in tensorflow, which behaves correctly with a rank2 input tensor of size `[None, n_features]`, weights of `[n_features, n_neurons]` which results in a hidden layer of `tf.matmul(inputs, weight) = [None, n_neurons]`.

However, I would like to expand my dimensionality by one dimension both in the input and the outputs. For example, I want to have

```
inputs = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, n_type, n_features])
weight= tf.Variable(FNN_weight_initializer([n_type, n_features, n_neurons]))
Hidden1 = tf.matmul(inputs, weight)
```

And my end goal here is to have `Hidden1 = [None, n_type, n_neurons]`.

However instead of generating the desired tensor shape, I instead get a tensor of shape `[n_type, n_type, n_neurons]`. I'm not an expert at linear algebra, and I've tried a few combinations of dimension order with no success. Is it even possible to multiply rank3 tensors with `tf.matmul`?  Should I be doing a reshape or transpose operation somewhere here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT according to OP's comment**

You could flatten the input feature vectors to shape `[-1, n_type * n_features]`, apply a well-chosen matrix multiplication and reshape your output from `[-1, n_type * n_neurons]` to `[-1, n_type, n_neurons]`

The operation tensor would be a block-diagonal `[n_type * n_features, n_type * n_neurons]` one, each block being one of the `n_type` tensors in `weights`.

To build a block-diagonal matrix, I used another answer (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42157781/block-diagonal-matrices-in-tensorflow))

This would look like

```
inputs = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, n_type, n_features])
inputs = tf.reshape(inputs, shape=[-1, n_type * n_features])

weights = tf.Variable(FNN_weight_initializer([n_type, n_features, n_neurons]))

split_weights = tf.split(weights, num_or_size_splits=n_type, axis=1)
# each element of split_weights is a tensor of shape : [1, n_features, n_neurons] -> need to squeeze
split_weights = tf.map_fn(lambda elt : tf.squeeze(elt, axis=0), split_weights)

block_matrix = block_diagonal(split_weights) # from the abovementioned reference

Hidden1 = tf.matmul(inputs, block_matrix)
# shape : [None, n_type * n_neurons]

Hidden1 = tf.reshape(Hidden1, [-1, n_type, n_neurons])
# shape : [None, n_type, n_neurons]
```

---

**Orignal answer**

According to the documentation of `tf.matmul` ([reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/matmul)), the tensors you are multiplying need to be of the same rank.

When the rank is `>2`, only the last two dimensions need to be matrix multiplication compatible, the first other dimensions need to be exactly matching.

So, to the question "Is it even possible to multiply rank3 tensors with tf.matmul?", the answer is "Yes, it is possible, but conceptually, it is still rank 2 multiplication".

Therefore, some reshaping is necessary:

```
inputs = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, n_type, n_features])

inputs = tf.reshape(inputs, shape=[-1, n_type, 1, n_features])

weights = tf.Variable(FNN_weight_initializer([n_type, n_features, n_neurons]))

weights = tf.expand_dims(weights, 0)
# shape : [1, n_type, n_features, n_neurons]

weights = tf.tile(weights, [tf.shape(inputs)[0], 1, 1, 1])
# shape : [None, n_type, n_features, n_neurons]

Hidden1 = tf.matmul(inputs, weights)
# shape : [None, n_type, 1, n_neurons]

Hidden1 = tf.reshape(Hidden1, [-1, n_type, n_neurons])
# shape : [None, n_type, n_neurons]
```

Comment: This appears to correct my dimension problem - although it appears that the use of tf.tile on 'inputs' can easily generate an out of memory error because it seems to be allocating space for a tensor equal to the entire size of input (even though I am running batches). Can it be done without reference to the 'inputs' tensor?

Comment: I agree with your comment. It seems that the only way is to flattten the inputs features and multiply them by a rank 2 block-diagonal tensor, then reshape the output. See edit

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts - more complex than I thought!   Should split_weights refer to axis=0 instead?  I get an error with 1, but with axis = 0 I generate a list of n_type tensors each with size [1, n_features, n_neurons].  (seems correct).  But when I pass this split_weights into the map_fn I get ValueError: Can not squeeze dim[0], expected a dimension of 1, got 30 for 'map_18/while/Squeeze' (op: 'Squeeze') with input shapes: [30,2,20]. This doesn't make sense to me b/c split_weights is a list of 30 tensors of size [1, n_features, n_neurons], so I thought map_fn should work ...